# Magento 2 how to hide columns in customer listing grid

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, customer-grid

I want to hide some columns from customer listing grid. I try to use false in customer_listing.xml, but it doesn't work. And I noticed that some columns (for example "confirmation", "created_in", "billing_full") in magento's ui component xml file have options visible = false but they don't hide in grid.
How can I hide this columns? I don't want to  disable them, just hide them.
Thanks in advance.
P.S. I want to change visability from code for all new admin users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I created before plugin for class vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/BookmarkManagement.php and method loadByNamespace.
I created new bookmarks for current customer with my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow code with create custom `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml` file.

It works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="billing_telephone">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_postcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

I hope this will help you